# How do I select a href="mailto" tag on a page?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I can use either xpath or CSS, doesn't matter...but there are other `a` tags on the page. But I just want to use either the first `a href=mailto:` tag or anyone (there is actually just one, so it doesn't matter the order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an XPath [`starts-with`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-starts-with) function:

```
mailto = doc.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto:")]').first
```

The standardese is particularly thick in the XPath spec so hopefully the example is clear enough.

Comment: +1; if you want to lean more on Ruby: [`mailto = doc.css('a').find{ |a| a['href'] =~ /^mailto:/ }`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).